# Is this task freeze related to ReiserFS (v3)? (or: is ReiserFS getting so old that it should be actively replaced?)

Tags: logs, freeze, trace

I just had a weird system freeze that I resolved using alt-sysrq-e. Here's my dmesg: https://gist.github.com/1609263

I was wondering whether it might be some kind of deadlock in the reiserfs3 code since it's mentioned so many times (and in nearly all the call traces)? Or would it look the same with any other file system?

I just want to know if ReiserFS v3 is getting so old that I should bother reformatting, just to get rid of this. If this call trace would be produced with other filesystems too, I guess it's not resolvable by changing FS.

I've been running this system for years now daily, and I never had this problem before. Not running a bleeding edge kernel either, just the standard Ubuntu 10.10 (3.0.0-14).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran a Slackware system for 8 years using ReiserFS v3 as the main filesystem. I don't think I ever had a problem until the disk started having hardware problems. I looked at your messages, and although the problem *appears* to come from filesystem code, it also looks like ext3 messages are mixed in there.

Personally, I'd suspect a disk going bad, especially when you say "I've been running this system for years". Disks are complicated mechanically and electronically.  They do go bad, in strange and unpredictable ways.